# Opera: HTTP header Content-Disposition

Tags: http, opera

Like for any other browser I've tried (FF, IE, Chrome, Safari), I'd like Opera to prompt the user to save the returned file. Here is the reply details:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="foo.icc-schema"
Server: Jetty(6.1.25)
```

Opera is ignoring the attachment and tries to open the returned file as a reguler HTML document. Any idea?

Comment: Did you figure out what was the issue? I am facing the same thing on Opera Mini

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Content-Type to `binary/octet-stream`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Cache-Control header confuses Opera?